# SSIS Configuration and deployment to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, deployment, configuration, ssis

I have SSIS 2008 package with Data Flow tasks and various package level variables. I am trying to deploy this package to SQL Server 2008 and want the user to some how set the variables while executing the package in SQL Server. Can some one help me on deployment and a way to set the variables?

**EDIT**

I installed my package both under File system and MSDB but not sure how to pass in the variable values.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it done by adding a Configuration file. I can include each and everything in this file, like variables, connection strings, properties and whatever you need to control with this configuration file.